# Realizar una acción condiconal en un ajax con jquery según respuesta en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy haciendo un formulario de contacto para mi pagina web, y estoy usando el metodo Ajax de Jquery, lo cual me debe arrogar una respuesta cuando mi php devuelva una respuesta pero resulta que no está pasando porque al parece el Ajax no coge el valor que esta en mi php con success, me podrían ayudar a resolverlo (soy nuevo en ajax)

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $correo = $_POST['mail'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $comunicacion = $_POST['comunicacion'];
    $patron = '/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ, ]*$/';
    $mensajeError = '';
    $toSend = "true";

    if($comunicacion == "tophone"){
        $medio = "telefono";
    }else{
        $medio = "correo";
    }

    if(empty($nombre)){
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "Complete el campo de nombre"."</br>";
    } else{
        if(!preg_match($patron,$nombre)){
            $toSend = "false";
            $mensajeError .= "El campo nombre no puede contener numeros"."</br>";
        }
    }

    if(strlen($nombre)>=35){
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "El nombre es muy largo"."</br>";
    }

    if(!empty($empresa)){
        if(strlen($empresa)>=30){
            $toSend = "false";
            $mensajeError .= "El nombre de la empresa es muy largo"."</br>";
        }
    }else{
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "El campo empresa esta vacío"."</br>";
    }
    
    if(!empty($correo)){
        if(!filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $toSend = "false";
            $mensajeError .= "Ingrese un correo valido"."</br>";
        }
    }else{
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "El campo correo esta vacío"."</br>";
    }

    if(!empty($telefono)){
        if(is_numeric($telefono) && (strlen($telefono)==7 or strlen($telefono)==9)){
        }else{
            $toSend = "false";
            $mensajeError .= "Teléfono incorrecto"."</br>";
        }
    }else{
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "El campo telefono esta vacío"."</br>";
    }

    if(!empty($mensaje)){
    }else{
        $toSend = "false";
        $mensajeError .= "El campo mensaje esta vacío"."</br>";
    }

    if($toSend == "true"){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo $mensajeError;
    }
```

Y este es mi llamado en mi js, en la parte de console de la pagina me envia el mensaje: "No esta funcionando success" lo cual me hace entender que si recibe la respuesta pero para ajax la igualdad o la comparación no esta funcionando.

```
$('#formContacto').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datosContacto= new FormData($('#formContacto')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:"php/enviarmail.php",
        type:"post",
        data: datosContacto,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#msgSuccessMail").html("Mensaje enviando...")
        },
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "success"){
                console.log(response);
            }else{
                console.log("no esta funcionado " + response);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Parece que `response` está llegando con algún salto de línea adicional. Pon la comparación así: `if(response.trim()== "success"){` y dinos si ahora entra en la 1ª parte del if.

Comment: Eres un genio, funciono de maravilla, gracias por el dato parece que si estaba devolviendo un salto de linea.

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir mucho, por lo que es recomendable trabajar con JSON, es un formato más ligero, menos propenso a errores y te ayuda a manejar mejor la lógica de tu programa. De hecho todas esas validaciones deberían hacerse del lado del cliente y en el servidor solo verificarlas el estado de las variables y controlarías el flujo, respondiendo con un JSON con una clave `error` si hubiera alguno, o un JSON con los datos. Luego en el `success` harías algo así: `if(response.error) { //lo que sea } else { //leer, mostrar datos }`

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto...y no entiendo mucho de Ajax recien estoy aprendiendo y que bueno toparme con gente como tú que ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en la consola se imprime: `No esta funcionando success`, es evidente que desde el servidor estás recibiendo en efecto la palabra `success`, **pero con algo más**, y ese *algo más* puede ser un salto de línea, un espacio en blanco, algún carácter invisible pero que altera el contenido (BOM), etc.

Generalmente, cuando en PHP no cierras el bloque de código con `?>` o no usas `exit()` en la última línea, se agrega a la salida un salto de línea.

Para **limpiar** el valor retornado podrías usar `trim()`, por ejemplo:

```
if(response.trim()== "success"){
    // ...
}
```

De todos modos no es una buena idea estar limpiando valores. Te recomendaría que, si vas a trabajar con Ajax, uses JSON para las respuestas. Es mucho menos propenso a errores, más ligero y más flexible. Con JSON puedes estructurar mejor los datos y establecer tu propia política de manejo de errores con respecto a la respuesta desde PHP.

Para trabajar con JSON sólo tienes que agregar a la petición Ajax este parámetro: [`dataType: 'json'`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y en PHP crearías la respuesta como un array y la devolverías con `echo json_encode($mData);` donde `$mData` es un array que podría contener los datos o algún evento de error no de servidor, sino de lógica de tu propio programa.

Por poner un ejemplo, supongamos una petición Ajax que hace una consulta a la base de datos. Hay dos posibilidades, que haya datos o que no haya datos, lo cual sería un error no de servidor, sino propio de la lógica del programa (datos no encontrados, error de consulta SQL, clave duplicada, etc son errores que deberían ser controlados con una política clara de control de errores en comunicación cliente/servidor).

En el flujo del código PHP controlarías la lógica, llenando la respuesta con algo como esto si hay datos: `$mData=array('nombre'=>Juan, 'apellido'=>Pérez)` o algo como esto si no hay datos: `$mData=array('error'=>'Juan Pérez no existe en la BD')`. **La clave** es que `$mData` será siempre un array el cual imprimirás al final del flujo con `echo json_encode($mData);`. Así, en la parte `success` de Ajax no tendrás errores como lo del `trim()` y podrás implementar tu política propia de control de errores con algo como esto:

```
    success: function(response){
        if(response.error){
            //Hubo error, mostrarlo o hacer lo que sea
            console.log(response.error);
        }else{
            //No hubo error, mostrar los datos o hacer lo que sea preciso;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza serialize:

```
 var datosContacto= $('#formContacto').serialize();
```

y fijate si envia todo correctamente al ajax y captura los errores con;

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
alert(xhr.statusText); 
alert(xhr.responseText); 
alert(xhr.status); 
alert(thrownError); 
},
```